# onSubmitEditing not working on TextInput when Multiline={true} in React Native(android)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

On iOS there is no problem, but on Android when I have multiline TextInput, onSubmitEditing doesn't seem to work. User types some symbols in input and when pressing return key I am expecting to stop typing option, save already typed symbols, but instead new line appears below and user continues to type.

```
<TextInput
  multiline
  onSubmitEditing={text => this.saveCurrentValues()}
/>
```

Answer (score 3):

If the Textinput's Multiline is set to true, onSubmitEditing prop won't work. Since multiline requires Return key to jump to the next line. This info is explicitly stated in the React Native TextInput docs page.

Comment: I do not think this is true, on iOS it works as expected. When pressing return key it doesn't go to new line but listens to onSubmitEditing

Comment: http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#onsubmitediting

Comment: "Callback that is called when the text input's submit button is pressed. Invalid if multiline={true} is specified." - RN Docs on onSubmitEditing.

Comment: Then why are functionalities on two different OS systems different? Very weird!

Comment: Wow! Haven't thought about it much. Need to look into it :D I hope you found the above answer helpful.